# "captcha.php" not generating response on local server

Tags: php, html, xampp, captcha

HTML

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post"> 
Comment: <textarea name="coment"></textarea> 
Enter Code <img src="captcha.php"><input type="text" name="vercode" /> 
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

captcha.php

```
<?php 


error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
session_start(); 
header( "Content-type: image/jpeg");
$text = rand(10000,99999); 
$_SESSION["vercode"] = $text; 
$height = 25; 
$width = 65; 
$image_p = imagecreate($width, $height); 
$black = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 0, 0, 0); 
$white = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 255, 255, 255); 
$font_size = 14; 

imagestring($image_p, $font_size, 5, 5, $text, $white); 
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 80); 
?>
```

I have xammp setup on my pc and when i run this the problem i am facing is the captcha.php gets fired but it does not give back an image as a response. I tried searching many forums and the above php code appears to be working fine with everyone else. I doubt anything that i might be doing wrongly on my local environment setup with xampp.

Comment: Please make sure that you have error reporting or logging enabled, then call captcha.php directly and check the output. Maybe you are just missing PHP's GD extension.

Comment: i have enabled error_reporting in php but i don't know anything about GD extension...can i get some help in that area...sorry but m a kind of noob in php.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell to the browser that you are sending image by setting proper header. In this case it'll be `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` in first lines of your code.

Comment: Sorry for that..i already had the content header line but missed it while posting the code...even though the header is added still i do not get any response from captcha.php in network tab.

Comment: @SanandiyaAakash In that case you have to do like Māris Kiseļovs said and add error reporting / logging to let us know what is really happening there.

Comment: enabled error reporting but no error's there..i guess that GD extension thing has something to do with my bug.

Comment: You can check if you've got GD using `phpinfo()` function.

Comment: checked phpinfo() and GD support is enabled and working fine..!

Comment: @SanandiyaAakash So now comment out `header()` and check again with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` (directly, not from your html). With headers set, browser will just show `broken image` or blank page if there is anything other than image (eg. errors).

Comment: did that...browser shows random text with some design alike noise...although it has one line which says

����JFIF��;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 80 ��C  %# , #&')*)-0-(0%()(��C   (((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((��A"��  ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br�

Comment: @SanandiyaAakash I saw your question update. Why you used `image/gif` content-type when you outputting jpeg?